# Creating 3D models from point clouds

Tags: windows, modeling

What are the leading software available for creating 3D models from point clouds?

Commercial, freeware as well as open source on Windows platform.

We have the point cloud from scanners. Scanned from industries basically piping and could be buildings and landscapes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Kinect I think http://reconstructme.net has a good one I know of that the people in the Microsoft Kinect forum have talked about a fair bit from time to time. P.S. you will need mesh lab to convert the 3D object to a format usable for games or simulations. 
If I am talking about the wrong software please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The best software as far as i know for point cloud processing in open source world is meshlab, windows have  geomagic studio, rapidform, freeform (i think owned by geomagic all them) all for reverse engineering, may be if you provide data about the final use for the model I could be more helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Other options could be tried
https://pix4d.com/

Autodesk Recap
http://www.autodesk.com/products/recap/overview